# How to suppress stylecop/fxcop/visual studio code analysis for auto generated file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, antlr, stylecop

I have C# code generated from ANTLR. How do I tell stylecop/fxcop/visual studio code analysis to ignore this file in checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FxCop, the definitive method is to decorate your code with a `[GeneratedCode]` attribute and disable the option to check generated code. The details differ between VS and/or FxCop versions; see this blog post for [correct usage of the attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/04/27/correct-usage-of-the-compilergeneratedattribute-and-the-generatedcodeattribute.aspx).

StyleCop ignores that attribute, but you have a few other options:

- Name your file "Whatever.Designer.cs" and set that option in your StyleCop.settings file.
- Include an XML header on the file that includes `<auto-generated />` somewhere in it.

In addition, the most recent versions of both tools appear to ignore code that is inside a region that includes the phrase "generated code" in its name. For example, in your Windows Forms *.Designer.cs files you will see this:

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent ( )
{
    // stuff here
}

#endregion
```

Code Analysis and StyleCop with both ignore the code within that region, but will still run against the remainder of this file. (If you have the "Ignore designer files" option set, of course, StyleCop will ignore the entire file because it ends in .Designer.cs.)

It is very frustrating that the two tools cannot seem to agree on how to ignore code (almost as frustrating as the amount of auto-generated code that doesn't bother to exclude itself properly -- looking at you here, EF.) The problem, is that Code Analysis checks your compiled code (which has attribute metadata but no comments), while StyleCop checks your source code (where the scope of metadata attributes are harder to track, though it would still be possible).

In my templates I tend to use a mixture of options: I include a StyleCop-aware header with the `<auto-generated>` tag in it, and then decorate each code element with `[GeneratedCode]`, and it seems to catch everything. (Possibly goes without saying that my autogenerated code also tries really hard not to violate the rules in the first place :) )

Answer (score 1):

The other method might be using @headers.

```
@lexer::header {
    #pragma warning disable 1591
}

@parser::header {
    #pragma warning disable 1591 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i noticed that the ANTLR generated files are 'partially', so i just created a second file, added the same class also as 'partially' without the class having any field or method, but added the following attribute to the class:

[GeneratedCodeAttribute("ANTLR", "3.0.0.0")]

Then i checked this file in, into TFS source control. Like this, the class has the generated code attribute set and CodeAnalysis/FxCop will ignore the entire class. But you will have to configure CodeAnalysis, to not check auto generated code (appropriate checkbox set to checked).